# Set annotation meta properties programmatically

Tags: java, annotations

Is it possible to set properties of annotation programmatically. So if I have :

```
@interface Author(
    String name();
    Date date ();
)
```

I want to be able to set the name property inside the code as if it is a regular class. Is this possible?

Comment: According to https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params that is possible, though not trivial.

Answer (score 2):

- You can't use `Date` in an annotation
- To access it at runtime, you need to add the `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` retention policy
- The declaration for annotations uses `{}` for the annotation definition, not `()`
- **No, you can't modify annotations during runtime using normal Java functionality**
- You may do this using a bytecode manipulator, like [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/). But that is is not trivial.

Why do you want to do this during runtime? Possibly there are other better solutions to your problem.